# How can I display columns with the same name from two different tables?

Tags: php, sql

I have made an SQL query from two tables. Everything works good but problem is that this two tables have the same field names and after I do not know how to display them correct, how to tell that    $data['aaa'] is from table 1 and the same $data['aaa'] from table 2

here is my SQL query :

```
    $query_str = "SELECT 
                    cm.id,
                    cm.global_category_id,
                    cm.num,
                    cm.menu_lv,
                    cm.menu_ru,
                    cm.menu_en,
                    u.id,
                    u.menu_lv,
                    u.menu_ru,
                    u.menu_en
                    FROM products_category cm, products_global_category u
                    WHERE cm.global_category_id = u.id
                    ";
```

and display data

```
<? foreach ($sub_category_list as $line) : ?>
<tr>
   <td><?=$line['menu_lv']?></td>   <---- here I want to display data from products_global_category u       
   <td><?=$line['sub_menu_lv']?></td>   <---- products_category cm
   <td><?=$line['sub_menu_ru']?></td>   <---- products_category cm
   <td><?=$line['sub_menu_en']?></td>   <---- products_category cm
</tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a solution you can change your SQL query to give an alias to the fields that have the same name.

For example:

```
SELECT somefield AS othername FROM table.
```

In this case, the `somefield` field will be available through the alias `othername`.

In your case:

```
$query_str = "SELECT 
                cm.id AS cm_id,
                cm.global_category_id,
                cm.num,
                cm.menu_lv AS cm_menulv,
                cm.menu_ru AS cm_menuru,
                cm.menu_en AS cm.menuen,
                u.id as u_id,
                u.menu_lv AS u_menulv,
                u.menu_ru AS u_menuru,
                u.menu_en AS u_menuen
                FROM products_category cm, products_global_category u
                WHERE cm.global_category_id = u.id
                ";
```

And then in your PHP:

```
$line['u_menulv'] //Access field menu_lv from products_global_category table
$line['cm_menulv'] //Access field menu_lv from products_category table
```

**EDIT:** In `mysql_fetch_array` [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the
>   last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the
>   same name, you must use the numeric index of the column or make an
>   alias for the column. For aliased columns, you cannot access the
>   contents with the original column name.

In other words, either create an alias like shown above or access the fields by the numeric index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Simply alias the records you wish to print out which conflict with one another, for example:

```
SELECT
   table1.pid AS page_id,
   table2.pid AS product_id
FROM
   table1
LEFT JOIN
   table2
ON
   table1.id = table2.id
```

And then within your PHP you can echo them out as follows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['page_id'];
    echo $row['product_id'];
}
```

Hope this helps!